# How it works the coordinate system of img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have the same image (200x200) for both cases. I'm implementing template matching, so the idea is to use the rectangle region of this code like template:

```
image = cv.imread('some-image.tif', 0)
cv.rectangle(image,(150, 50),(200,100),(255,0,0),2)
plt.imshow(image, 'gray')
plt.title('With rectangle')
plt.show()
```

But when I run the following line in the template matching code, the rectangle is not the same of the code above:
`template = image[50:100, 150:200]`

Why I don't get the same ROI? I know that the form is `[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Answer (score 3):

**I think you line `image = cv.imread(image, 0)` is not correct syntax. You need to use an actual filename.suffix in cv.imread()`**

Your commands work fine for me in Python/OpenCV 3

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('zelda1.jpg')
cv2.rectangle(img,(150, 50),(200,100),(255,0,0),1)

roi = img[50:100, 150:200]

cv2.imwrite('zelda1_rect.jpg', img)
cv2.imwrite('zelda1_roi.jpg', roi)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("roi", roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Image with rectangle:

[image]

ROI:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are right! I don't know why gives me another output. The only difference is that I used ```plt.imshow()```

Comment: pyplot plt.imshow applies a color map to the result where as opencv cv2.imshow does not. So you likely wlll get color changes. But I would not think that it should display a different subsection.